# Passing C++ class object to next viewController in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a c++ class

```
class camera{
    int x, y;
    float dir;
}; 

camera bestcam[20];
```

now i want to pass the array of objects of this class to next ViewController but i am getting error in doing so. I have included this class in my viewController's class also but i am getting error.

Comment: For us to help you, you should add the code that is erroring, and the error.

Comment: is your ViewController in a file that ends with "`.mm`"?

Comment: i am adding @property cameras *bestconfig; in my viewcontroller's header file but it is giving me error "unknown type name cameras", though i have included cameras.h

Comment: yeah i have changed the extension to .mm

Comment: thanks to everyone, i got it right. The probelm was with xcode it refreshes itself when i explicitly build the project and then error is gone, and the error was not saving it with .mm extension. Thank you all